# WhereParameters cannot be specified unless AutoGenerateWhere==true or Where is specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a strange error when I try to change my website . I got always the same error

> `WhereParameters` cannot be specified unless `AutoGenerateWhere ==
>    true` or Where is specified.

I already checked out my EntityDataSource it should be ok. There is no typical parameter error where the name has a @ in front

```
 <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=HolidayTrackerEntities" DefaultContainerName="HolidayTrackerEntities"
        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="PublicVacations" Where="it.BusinessUnitId == @BusinessUnitId">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter DbType="Int32" SessionField="BusinessUnitId" Name="BusinessUnitId" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I get the same message after Rebuild, Clean...

Thanks for help and fast answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My be you should adda AutoGenerateWhereClause = "true" i hope it help

Answer (score 1):

For the Telerik RadGrid, this can be caused by the `AllowFilteringByColumn="true"` setting. If you need custom filtering in addition to a default `Where` control clause, you can see the demo [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-filter-and-the-entitydatasource-control-whereparameters) from Rosen in the forum post.